# Laravel Livewire Filter Number of Transaction by User

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel Livewire for my project. In my project there are three tables. Users, Orders, and Order details. Users are allowed to have multiple orders. In my Orders table each order is saved with user_id. I have generated a Users Table and now i am building a filter in which I want to query users tables that which users have more orders. I want to pass an integer value to filter the users.
i.e If I pass 10 then it will filter users who have ordered more than 10 orders

I have also passed the Relation to Orders Model in my User Model Like this

```
public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'user_id');
    }
```

I am trying like this but its not returning required result

```
if ($orders_num = ($filters['orders_num'] ?? false))
                $user = $user->orders()->count('user_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways.

1. Use Eloquent `withCount()`, in combination with condition.

   ```
   $threshold = 10;
   $users = User::withCount('orders')
   ->get()
   ->where('orders_count', '>', $threshold);
   ```
2. Use Eloquent `has()`

   ```
   $users = User::has('orders', '>', $threshold)
       ->get();
   ```
3. Use `Collection::map()`

   ```
   $users = User::with('orders')
       ->get()
       ->filter(function ($user) use ($threshold) {
           return $user->orders->count() > $threshold;
       });
   ```